# TImage Stretch XE5

Tags: android, delphi, bitmap, delphi-xe5, timage

in XE5, using TImage, how can I stretch a bitmap with his proportional dimensions? The TImage has 200 pixels width  and 300 pixels height. And the bitmap has 130 width and 80 height. When I set Image1.WrapMode to iwStretch the bitmap is resized to fit the TImage's area, but not in the scale proportion of TImage, the bitmap then shows too "fat".

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is not [`TImage.WrapMode = iwFit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Objects.TImage.WrapMode) what you are looking for? It will keep the proportions of the image.

Comment: iwFit is even the default .....

Comment: Ok, but when i set it to iwFit the image(bitmap) does not fit the height and width. The size stays the same that iwOriginal. It's a bug?

Comment: Ahh, [`doc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Objects.TImageWrapMode) says, that `iwFit` only can shrink the image (proportionally) if it does not fit. Upscaling is not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain proportionals you can use the "scale" property.
For example, you load an image in img (TImage) on a form and with a button you want to scale it you can do this:

```
procedure THeaderFooterForm.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var testScale : Single;
begin
 img.WrapMode := TImageWrapMode.iwOriginal;
 testScale :=  img.Width / img.Bitmap.Width;
 if (img.Height / img.Bitmap.Height) < testScale then
    testScale := img.Height / img.Bitmap.Height;


 img.Scale.X := testScale;
 img.Scale.Y := testScale;



end;
```